# Force close connections on mango db that runs in atlas cloud

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have a mango db cluster hosted on AWS via [atlas cloud offering](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas).
Problem: I have gotten myself into a situation where I have idle/stale connections connected to my cluster and I can't seem to get rid of them.

The connection count is 98 and my tier allows be to have just 100.

I do have ability to connect to this cluster via Mango Shell or other tooling, but I can't seem to find a way to restart the service or to force close the connections.

Now I do not have access to the underlying container or VM so I can't control control the mango service.

When I connect through the shell I tried

```
db.runCommand( { killAllSessions: [ ] } )
```

but that gave me

`{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "CMD_NOT_ALLOWED: killAllSessions",
        "code" : 8000,
        "codeName" : "AtlasError"
}`

The user I'm connecting with to the shell has the max permissions - it's atlasAdmin@admin role (I also tried with 
clusterMonitor@admin role)

I also can't seem to find any restart options in the mango cloud manager web UI

Answer (score 17):

This is what I ended up doing.

Since I was on M0 tier my only option was to remove all IP's from the IP Whitelist - that immediately closed all external connections to my cluster. Then I re-added the needed IPs back.

If I was on a higher tier I could have also tried this approach - https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/tutorial/test-failover/

Comment: Works with M10 as well